# Why does Mac Lion reverse the direction of my mouse scroll?

Tags: mac, osx-lion

After installing Lion on my mac, the scroll on my mouse is now reversed and I find it very awkward.

Is this a "feature"? How can I revert to the normal method of scrolling?

Answer (score 12):

This is indeed a "feature". It's called "natural scrolling", and was likely done to increase the similarity of the experience between iOS devices and OS X. You can turn it off from the mouse settings panel in System Preferences by unchecking "scroll direction: natural".

[image: turn off natural scrolling]

<sub>(Image from [post on Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17795/can-i-reverse-the-two-finger-scrolling-direction-in-os-x-lion-10-7))</sub>

Comment: Apparently, this was done so that content follows scrolling direction. Before, the scrollbar moved in the scroll direction, so that if you two-finger dragged down, the scrollbar moved down but the content moved up. Now the content moves in the scroll direction, so that if you two-finger drag down, the content moves up but the scrollbar moves down.

Answer (score 4):

After first installing Lion, there's a screen you have to go through before proceeding:

[image: Screenshot of Lion post-install]
(Screenshot from [this Engadget review](http://www.engadget.com/2011/07/20/apple-os-x-lion-10-7-review/))

It does explain how to change the toggle this feature if you don't care for it.

Comment: Nicely pointed out how the OP clicked away huge, important dialogs with animations after installation without reading them and then wondered what the hell was going on.

Answer (score 1):

Roaming around the System Preferences pane in Lion will reveal that a great many of the new Lion features can be disabled or altered in some way. Which is nice, since I've found I only like half of them. Terminal commands are available for many others.

There's also a nice app, *Lion Tweaks* that - as the name suggests - handles some of this for you. The site for the utility is http://ifredrik.com/applications .